# Roles other than Super admin accessing manage_network_themes

Tags: multisite, network-admin

We currently use the Wordpress Multisite and Networks to control a few blogs of ours.

We are looking to give other users on the network permission to manage the themes on the network.

We've installed a few plugins to manage roles, create roles and modify the roles permissions.. but we haven't managed to find a solution.

Basically we are trying to allow roles other than Superadmin access to manage_network_themes.

The role we are trying to allow access to this has the permission checked, but they still can't access the network themes.

Is this area locked down to Super admins only? Is there a way around this?

We want to allow our other blogs access to manage themes, but we don't want to give them super admin access.

I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Including a list of capabilities you've given to the roles that still can't access manage_network_themes would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

First Deactivate all plugins or code used to modify the roles.

Under the Super Admin -> Users menu, find the user you wish to promote. Hover over their username and a small “edit” link will appear beneath it. Click it. This will lead you to the user’s profile page.

Scroll down to the “Name” section, you will see the checkbox selected to make this user a Super Admin on your site. Hit the update button to save the chage, and the user now has access to the Super Admin menu.

Check if the user now can manage themes, if ok, activate the plugins or code and this time block or remove the functions that you don't wish to give access to that user.

Answer (score -1):

I know this topic is a bit old but maybe someone stumbles unpon it just like me and still need an answer. I had the same problem, only for activation plugins, I posted a fix on my website. You could use it for you needs (change roles and capabilities).

Here is the [link](http://www.snippetz.nl/wordpress/normal-admin-plugin-activation-on-wordpress-multisite-install/).

Let me know if this helped you!

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link this answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer as stand-alone as possible.

Comment: Also, are you affiliated with Snippetz? I am guessing you are. If so, that makes your link-only answer that points to a Snippetz URL look pretty "spammie".